# I need to retrieve information from a web page. I need to get the player names from the url in the code with the tag '<span style="font-size:12px;">'

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "http://www.hltv.org/match/2294502-clg-liquid-esea-invite-season-18-na"

#sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
sock = Request(url, "headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}")

#myhtml = sock.read()
myhtml = urlopen(sock).read()

for item in myhtml.split("</span>"):
    if '<span style="font-size:12px;">' in item:
            print (item [ item.find('<span style="font-size:12px;">' + len('<tag>')) : ])
```

this is the error that is split out when i compile and run the code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/hltv.py", line 10, in <module>
    myhtml = urlopen(sock).read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 453, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1104, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

i am fairly new to python so please try to make the fix as simple as possible thanks. (Currently using python 3.x)

Comment: Is your code for Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: i am using python 3x in this code however if you could write the code in python 2x it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite it using Python 2

Notice that the parenthesis of the last line!

It should be
`item.find(TAG) + len(TAG)`
, not 
`item.find(TAG + len(TAG))`
in your code!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.hltv.org/match/2294502-clg-liquid-esea-invite-season-18-na")
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

TAG = '<span style="font-size:12px;">'
for item in the_page.split("</span>"):
    if TAG in item:
        print (item [ item.find(TAG) + len(TAG) : ])
```

### Result

```
hazed
ptr
FNS
tarik
reltuC
nitr0
adreN
FugLy
NAF-FLY
daps
```

## Note:

[BeautifualSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is more suitable for complex query of HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to parse `html`. There are standard libraries for your exact requirement such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers) . BeautifulSoup has various APIs to select tags etc.

**For Eg:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = urllib2.Request("http://www.hltv.org/match/2294502-clg-liquid-esea-invite-season-18-na")
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
soup = soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)


#To select all the span tags
span_tags = soup.find_all("span")

#To get the player names
player_names = soup.find_all("span" ,attrs={"style":"font-size:12px;"})
```